# Insert query inside 2 dimensional array using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on this simple query inside two dimensional array, my problem is its not working, and the error says  `Array to string conversion`. I tried using implode but didn't work too. Hope you help me.

```
Array( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 04:56:27am 
        [1] => http://www.industrialknive.com/# 
        [2] => 200 
        [3] => 0 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 04:56:28am 
        [1] => http://www.industrialknive.com/# 
        [2] => 200 
        [3] => 0 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 04:56:30am 
        [1] => mailto:support@industrialknive.com 
        [2] => 301 
        [3] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

Code:

```
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;

for($i=0; $i < count($arrList); $i++){

    for($ii=0; $ii < count($arrList[$i]); $ii++){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO links (website, scanned_at, site_url, url_code, is_external ) VALUES ('$last_id', '$arrList[$i][$ii]', '$arrList[$i][$ii]', '$arrList[$i][$ii]', '$arrList[$i][$ii]')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

    }   

}
```

Comment: Your array probably is three-dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's something. A couple of points: 1) PHP has a [`foreach` construct](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) so you don't need to use old fashioned `for` loops. 2) You're leaving yourself open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) by using string concatenation to build your query. 3) You're running that query once for every element of every array.

It's been a while since I worked with mysqli, but something like this should work:

```
<?php
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;
$query = "INSERT INTO links (website, scanned_at, site_url, url_code, is_external ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
    foreach ($arrList as $arr) {
        $stmt->bind_param("isssi", $last_id, $arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2], $arr[3]);
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Error executing: " . $sql . "<br>" . $stmt->error;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Error preparing: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: thanks it it really works, thanks also on the advice